# If the the difference of two consecutive terms of a sequence goes to zero, is the sequence bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\rightarrow0~(n\rightarrow\infty)$, the sequence itself does not necessarily have a limit (or not necessarily Cauchy). But must the sequence be bounded?

Comment: Clarify the statement. "limit of two consecutive terms of a sequence goes to zero"? Individual terms don't have limits,

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be bounded. Look at the harmonic numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an increasing sequence of reals converge if the difference of consecutive terms approaches zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116417/does-an-increasing-sequence-of-reals-converge-if-the-difference-of-consecutive-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the sequence does not need to be bounded.

Consider, for example, $a_n=\sqrt{n}$. We have
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} < \frac1{2\sqrt{n}}\to 0$$
Of course, $\sqrt{n}\to \infty$. This sequence is not bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Another, easy to remember example is $\log (n)$. $\log (n)$ tends to infinity, hence is not bounded. However, we have:

$$
|\log(n + 1) - \log (n)| = \left|\log \left( \frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right| 
$$
Which tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$
.